# check if two integer ranges overlap

Tags: python, range

I have two ranges, and I want to check if the ranges overlap at all. I've converted the ranges to lists and am checking if one value in the readRegion is in the refRegion, but this is super slow. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
readRegion=[*range(end,start,1)] #this list is always 600 in length
refRegion=[*range(600000,600500,1)] #this range will vary
p=0
for i in readRegion:
    if i in refRegion and p < 10000:
        regReads.append(filteredReads[n])
        p=10000    
    p+=1
```

Comment: Why not check whether the low end of one is lower than the high end of the other, and vice versa?

Comment: Is your step always 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ranges overlap if the larger of their start values is less than the smaller of their stop values. This, of course, is if step is equal to 1.

```
def overlaps(x, y):
    return max(x.start,y.start) < min(x.stop,y.stop)

print(overlaps(range(10, 100), range(94, 200))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both ranges always have step 1:

```
a = range(end, start, 1)
b = range(600000, 600500, 1)
overlapping = (b.start <= a.start < b.stop) or (a.start <= b.start < a.stop)
```

If not, we have to be a bit more general:

```
def ranges_overlap(a: range, b: range) -> bool:
    if b.start <= a.start < b.stop:
        return (a.start - b.start) % b.step == 0
    if a.start <= b.start < a.stop:
        return (b.start - a.start) % a.step == 0
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def range_intersect(a: range, b:range) -> range:
...     assert a.step == b.step == 1
...     return range(max((a.start, b.start)), min((a.stop, b.stop)))
...
>>> range_intersect(range(1, 10), range(5, 20))
range(5, 10)
```

If you want to just check whether the overlap is nonzero, take `len` of the resulting range:

```
>>> len(range_intersect(range(1, 3), range(5, 10)))
0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If your region is always `step=1`, i.e. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`,

   Simply run a check on your range, i.e. comparing your `end` and `start` against your `refRegion` range, then calculate the difference.
2. If your region is not necessarily always `step = 1`, i.e. sometimes `1, 3, 5, 7, 9`, given `step = 2`

   Include the step in your calculation, pointed out by @orlp's answer
3. If you region does not follow any step at all, such as `1, 5, 11, 31, 99`

   Try to use `union` in `set`

   ```
   readRegion=[*range(end,start,2)] #this list is always 600 in length
   refRegion=[*range(600000,600500,1)] #this range will vary
   regionUnion = set(readRegion).intersection(set(refRegion))
   print(len(regionUnion))
   ```

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it is unnecessarily inefficient. And we're talking high memory usage as well as incredibly long runtime vs instant and no memory usage, so it's not just a small optimization.

Comment: Let alone that, if the integer range of OP doesn't necessarily follow a `step` pattern, using `union` would be the way to cater every cases.

Comment: Brute force is actually not necessary here.

Comment: @orlp Thanks for your reminder, I have fixed the code. And thanks for your understanding. Your support means quite a lot to me as a starter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` to check if the intersection of the two sets result in any value.

For example, you can do something as simple as :

```
>>> print (True) if set(range(1,100)) & set(range(90,150)) else print (False)
True

>>> print (True) if set(range(1,100)) & set(range(110,150)) else print (False)
False
```

If you were to convert these into a function, then you will have something like this:

```
def compare_ranges(x,y):
    return True if set(x) & set(y) else False

compare_ranges(range(1,100),range(110,150))
compare_ranges(range(1,100),range(90,150))
```

The output of these two will be:

```
False
True
```

The first one does not have any values that are common, the second one has values that are common.

You can also use the same function to check for strings or other datatypes.

```
compare(['a','b','c','d'],['a','c','e','f'])
compare(['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h'])
```

The output of this will be:

```
True
False
```